# Extract sub string from a variable ( using pattern match may be ) using bash unix?

Tags: bash

I have a value in a variable as :

```
partition_column='| PARTITIONED BY ( | | `part_col1` int, | | `part_col2` int) | | ROW FORMAT SERDE |'
```

I want to extract values between PARTITIONED BY and ROW FORMAT SERDE , in above case its part_col1 and part_col2

```
Desired output:
part_col1 part_col2
```

I have tried many commands nothing seems to be working :

```
result=$(echo $par_col | sed -nr '/`/p'|  cut -d '`' -f 2|xargs -n 1 echo -n "")
```

could you please correct above command , or suggest something else?

Comment: Please tag your question using the _bash_ tag, if you are interested in only a bash solution. Further, your assignment statement `partition_column=....` is incorrect (did you ever try to copy and paste it to the command line), since it would interpret `part_col1` as the name of a command, and tries to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have installed GNU `cut`, the following would work in bash:

```
 partition_column='| PARTITIONED BY ( | | `part_col1` int, | | `part_col2` int) | | ROW FORMAT SERDE |'
 result=$(cut -d '`' -f 2,4 --output-delimiter=' ' <<<"$partition_column")
```

This takes the advantage, that the delimiters are really not the keywords you posted, but backquote characters. The `--output-delimiter` is necessary, because otherwise the fields would also be separated by a backquote in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
partition_column='| PARTITIONED BY ( | | `part_col1` int, | | `part_col2` int) | | ROW FORMAT SERDE |'
# extract everything between the patterns
<<<"$partition_column" sed 's/.*PARTITIONED BY\(.*\)ROW FORMAT SERDE.*/\1/' |
  # replace spaces for newlines
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  # filter only lines starting with \`
  grep '^`' |
  # remove the \`
  sed 's/`//g' |
  # join lines using a space
  paste -sd ' '
```

But it's possible with only `sed`, just use a global mask to first extract the chars within `, then replace them:

```
sed 's/.*PARTITIONED BY\(.*\)ROW FORMAT SERDE.*/\1/; s/[^`]*`\([^`]*\)`[^`]*/\1`/g; s/`/ /g; s/ $//;'
```

Or with sed you can loop with `t` until all the replacements are removed/shifted:

```
<<<"$partition_column" sed 's/.*PARTITIONED BY\(.*\)ROW FORMAT SERDE.*/\1/;
   # add a newline on the end
  s/$/\n/;
  :a;
     # find something within ` and move it behind the newline
     # remove everything in fron ` and after ` that is not a `
     s/[^`]*`\([^`]*\)`[^`]*\([^\n]*\n.*\)/\2 \1/;
  # loop until the `s` command above does something
  ta;
  # remove everything in front the newline and the space
  s/.*\n //;'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure bash solution, try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

partition_column='| PARTITIONED BY ( | | `part_col1` int, | | `part_col2` int) | | ROW FORMAT SERDE |'

left="${partition_column#*\`}"                  # remove everything until first `
target1="${left%%\`*}"                          # remove everything from first `
right="${partition_column%\`*}"                 # remove everything from last `
target2="${right##*\`}"                         # remove everything until last `

echo "$target1" "$target2"
```